Accessing all dendrite or axon compartment indices in Brian 2 neuronal mode
I am trying to create a neuronal model in Brian 2 based on a .swc file which has about 900 compartments.
I am importing the model morphology using morpho = Morphology.from_file()
I would like to plot  the voltage vs. time for all the axonal compartments as well as all the dendrites
but when I use the following:
axon_index = neuron[morpho.axon.indices[:]]
dendrite_index=neuron[morpho.apic.indices[:]]
I get:
dendrite compartments are: <Subgroup 'spatialneuron_subgroup_1' of 'spatialneuron' from 1 to 4>
axon compartments are:<Subgroup 'spatialneuron_subgroup' of 'spatialneuron' from 561 to 564>
There's way too few compartments listed. I would expect the answer for the axonal compartments to be something like 388-662. based on the swc file. Why aren't they listed?
Thanks,
Nick
I tried specifying additional subcompartments neuron[morpho.axon.axon.indices[:]] and I get indices for some compartments farther down the tree but I'd like to get the indices for the entire axon with all the subtrees
